# MaxLength textarea does not match varchar mysql

Tags: html, mysql

I have textarea html field and I say maxLength = 200.  My database is mySql. In a table there is a field where I put varchar(200). But I always got an exception because the input was longer than 200. Now I had to go down till maxLength = 193 then there was no exception anymore. So it seems textarea maxlength on client side does not fit varchar() on database side.

Comment: Are you counting the newlines (`\n`)?

Comment: I do not count anything. I rely on maxlength attrbute and on mysql :)